# How do you pack a flat-panel display without a custom-fitting box?

Tags: shipping, relocation

I have a flat-panel display (a computer monitor, but it might have been a TV for the purposes of this question) - but I don't have the box in which I got it, with the styrofoam support structure for absorbing shock and localized pressure.

I'm going to be moving soon, and need to pack it. Question is - how?

The actual panel decomposes from the base of the monitor.. The base is more massive, not flat obviously, but it's also not delicate so let's forget about that and focus this question on packing the panel itself.

Notes:

- The panel might travel by air, but it might also travel by sea.
- I pack my own boxes, so can't rely on movers.

Comment: This question might be more suited for lifehack.SE

Answer (score 2):

Option 1: Get the movers to pack it.  That way they are responsible for any damage.

Option 2: Lots of bubble wrap, and ideally inside something like a cupboard or linen-chest which will protect it from gross external stresses.

Edit: By "lots" I mean at least three layers, and at least a couple of cm total thickness.

Comment: Can you be more specific about "lots"? How many layers of what-size bubbles would be sufficient in your opinion?

Comment: @einpoklum Does that help?

Comment: @einpoklum another possibility: stores that sell such merchandise often discard the packaging of display items; you might ask.